# Can anyone tell me how to test my Camel Route if I have a choice operation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that has implemented a Content based Routing EIP(Choice operation). I need to test it. I'm new to Camel. So, I'm unsure how to do it.
Can anyone tell me how to test this operation. I have mentioned a sample code below that has to be tested.

```
public void configure() throws Exception 
{   
    onException(Exception.class).handled(true).bean(ErrorHandler.class).stop();

    from("{{input}}?concurrentConsumers=10")
    .routeId("Actions")
        .choice()
            .when().simple("${header.Action} == ${type:status1}")
                .bean(Class, "method1")
            .when().simple("${header.Action} == ${type:status2}")
                .bean(Class, "method2")
            .when().simple("${header.Action} == ${type:status3}")
                .bean(Class, "method3")
            .otherwise()
                .bean(Class, "method4")
        .end();       
}
```

Comment: You could try to [intercept](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html) the bean invocations or [advice](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) your root and add certain mock-endpoints after each bean-method invocation

Comment: You can also write some unit tests, see http://camel.apache.org/testing.html, to test your route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply "advice" your route and add mocks to each choice of your content-based router

```
public void testAdvised() throws Exception {
    // advice the first route using the inlined route builder
    context.getRouteDefinition("Actions").adviceWith(context, new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith("direct:start");
            weaveByToString(".*method1.*").after().to("mock:choice1");
            weaveByToString(".*method2.*").after().to("mock:choice2");
        }
    });

    getMockEndpoint("mock:choice1").expectedMessageCount(1);
    getMockEndpoint("mock:choice2").expectedMessageCount(0);

    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello World");

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

This probably needs a little more modifications to get it working. Let me know if you needed more clarification or a proper real test scenario for your route.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but in my case there was a predicate with `when` which would decide upon further action. It is not same as what is asked here, but I am still answering as it may help someone like me who is looking for it and comes to this page.

The route to be tested is:

```
from("direct:start").routeId("route1")
  .choice()
    .when(pred)  //pred is some predicate
      .to("log:choiceTrue")
    //.to(<some other route>)
  .otherwise()
      .to("log:choiceFalse")
    //.to(<some other route>)
  .end()
.end();
```

Since I was unable to mock the predicate to make it true or false as per my test condition, I replaced the entire choice segment with another similar route. For that I had to add a choice Id. Below is the entire code snippet.

```
public class PredicateTest extends CamelTestSupport{

protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {

        Predicate pred = exchangeProperty("sfs").isEqualTo("sdf");
        
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start").routeId("route1")
            .choice().id("choiceId")
               .when(pred)  //pred is some predicate
                  .to("log:choiceTrue")
                //.to(<some other route>)
            .otherwise()
                  .to("log:choiceFalse")
                //.to(<some other route>)
            .end()
            .end();
            
            
            from("direct:diversion")
            .to("log:divertedRoute")
            .choice()
                .when().simple("'abc' == 'abc'") //true condition
                    .to("log:TrueDiversion")
                    //.to(<some other route>)
            .otherwise()
                    .to("log:FalseDiversion")
                    //.to(<some other route>)
            .end()
            .end();
        }
        
    };
}
@Test
public void testMocksAreValid() throws Exception{
    
  RouteDefinition routeDef = context.getRouteDefinition("route1");
    
    AdviceWith.adviceWith(routeDef, context,
            new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                   weaveById("choiceId").replace()
                                        .to("direct:diversion");
                   weaveAddLast().to("mock:mockendpoint");
                }
            });
    
    context.start();
    template.requestBody("direct:start", "sampleBody");
    
    MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:mockendpoint");
    mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
    
    mock.assertIsSatisfied();
  }
}
```

Obviously, the commented `<some other route>` would be same in the `start` as well as `diversion` routes for the correct tests.